# Attempting a mouse movement simulator with Tkinter

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

**I'm working on a project**; It is supposed to upwards mouse movement on your mouse, example; shooting game recoil.

However, I'm faced with a huge issue that I can't wrap my head around; On Tkinter I can't have While Loops because of the way Tkinter was built and its continuous loop. 
I need to use the interface because I have a textlabel that is supposed to output if the mouse movement is happening or not.

**The goal**:
*The mouse movement only happens if the user creates a keyboard input, such as pressing 'z' ; mouse-simulator = on // recoil begins to act.*

Having some sort of loop to check for keyboard input while with Tkinter imported, and retrieving that data back to txtlabel, then starting the task of mouse movement until user decides to stop.

- Sorry If the way I worded is confusing. First time posting here.

**Example** of the code I had under my Tkinter program,

Program freezes with While Loop 
while True:
  # Check for input
  if keyboard.is_pressed('z'):
     movement_bool = not movement_bool

if movement_bool == True and mouse.is_pressed(button='left'):
      #use win32api to move mouse down

Comment: After press a key(such as `z`),it will have the upwards mouse movement.Right?

Comment: Please post the exact code that you have and a user is more likely to help you. You can use the code formatting by putting three ``` to open the code block and ``` to close the code block.

Comment: I’m confused, what is your question, exactly?

Comment: Why are you using tkinter if you're using the keyboard module and win32api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With tkinter you don't need to do a loop and check for keyboard presses. You can ask tkinter to call any function you want when it detects a key press and/or key release. The terminology is to *bind* an event to a function. When tkinter detects the requested event, it calls the function and passes an object representing the event.

Here's an example that prints a message when you press the "z" key:

```
import tkinter as tk

def handle_z(event):
    print("z was pressed")

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

# make sure that keyboard events are routed to the canvas
canvas.focus_set()

# call our function when the "z" key is pressed
canvas.bind("<z>", handle_z)

root.mainloop()
```